# win api - radio button event received twice

Tags: c, winapi

I have created a windows desktop application using visual studio 2019 template. I have added modeless dialog box which contains two radio buttons (BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON). When I select a radio button using mouse I receive a single radio button event but when I use arrow keys (up/down) to switch between radio buttons I get radio button event twice. Why ? How does it work ? A main message loop looks this way:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
{
    if (!IsDialogMessage(dialogBoxHandle, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Here is the modeless dialog box events procedure:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK MyProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case ID_RADIOBUTTON1:
            {
                std::cout << "ID_RADIOBUTTON1" << std::endl;
                return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
            }
        case ID_RADIOBUTTON2:
            {
                std::cout << "ID_RADIOBUTTON2" << std::endl;
                return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assuming that radio buttons can only send one kind of notification in a WM_COMMAND message. You check the low word of the WPARAM to find out which control is sending the message (which is correct), but you need to also check the high word of the WPARAM to find out what notification the control is sending. See [Button Control Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bumper-button-control-reference-notifications), and [WM_COMMAND message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command).